# Does the total energy have a physical meaning?

Tags: energy, education

Let us have a set {A, B, C, D, ... n} of physical objects. Each physical object has some energy value, but the elements of this set do not interact with each other in any way, there are no relationships between them (including causal ones), they are not entangled in any way and do not affect each other in any way (and do not jointly affect something other). Does the total energy of such a set have a physical meaning? If so, which one?

Comment: In what context? In QM?

Comment: @Qmechanic Without much context. There simply exists a physical system whose elements are not connected with each other in any way, do not interact, between them there are no relations, no correlations. Whether in quantum mechanics or in classical mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Energy does not have meaning without context. I could only think on its main property: may it be a function of the microscopic coordinates of the system, the eigenvalue of a ket, or a state function of the thermodynamic variables; the energy is conserved if the system is isolated.

So you could just say that the total energy will be constant if these subsystems are put in contact or they can start interacting in any way. This requirement can be seen as a constraint of the dynamics that these subsystems would follow if they were put in contact.

Comment: And if they don't make contact? can such a set be considered a system at all? Wherever I have looked, the system is defined as a set of interconnected elements.

Comment: I would say that in this case, although you can define the total energy, it is not of much use. I cannot think about many things to be said about the Energy in such a situation, apart from that whatever the subsystem's dynamics might be, the total energy should be conserved. So the subsystem's energies are bounded to the total energy.